# What AC switch wiring is this?

Tags: electrical

I have a switch in my den that controls an outlet on the far wall. Then top of the outlet is controlled by this switch and the bottom is always live.

When looking at the switch it has ground to the ground screw, both white and black wires connected to two screws where normally I've seen the black wire split and connected. When testing with a multimeter both read 120V.

I wanted to put a motion sensor switch here, but that requires ground, neutral, power. I'm guessing I will not be able to wire this new switch up?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have an old fashion switch loop.  If done right the white is hot(and suppose to have black tape on it) and the black is switched hot(but could be reverse).  You are right about not being able to use that new switch(without a rewire), but might be able to find one that does not need neutral.  Some smart switches are made this way, since most need neutral also.

Comment: You said that both white and black are hot (realtive to the ground), but this must be with the switch ON (usually up). Try this with the switch turned OFF(usually down). Should find that one and only one of the wires is hot.

Comment: @JimStewart  Some switches do allow that in their instructions/are made for that, but other switches do not, so would be against code if done.

Comment: So some switches are designed to use such little power (such low current) that the amount used is less than some threshold? The OP should read the instructions and see if the one he has allows this. Do the ones that allow the ground to be used as neutral have a physical arangement that hides this so that the installer won't see it and think, "This is not right."

Comment: @JimStewart  I only know what has been written on this site about them.

Comment: @JimStewart You're correct I forgot I had it switched on :-(

Comment: The one that is hot with the switch OFF is the line hot. The other is the switched hot (i.e., goes to the load). Unlike the old mechanical switches I suppose the smart switches require the line hot to go to a specific screw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's an old-style switch loop

What you have in the wall is an old-style, no-neutral switch loop.  This wiring arrangement is common in older work, but no longer Code in most cases after 2011 because it is incompatible with most smart switches, including yours.

Comment: Is it absolutely out of bounds to connect the light gray neutral and the green ground to the ground of the house wiring? Can you do this if the installation instructions for the smart switch would say that can be done? Are there any of these smart switches that use the ground for the neutral and somehow disguise this?

Comment: @JimStewart there are a few Lutron Maestro motion sensors that can use the ground or the neutral -- they'll say-so in their instructions.